# I need help getting age from D.O.B

Tags: php, mysql

I have a prebuilt website that takes a import of a CSV file and pulls data from that. The CSV file has a date of birth in (1994-12-31) format and is supposed to calculate from that the age. The code below is what is happening and I dont know what is wrong with it. Because instead of it outputting an age it is taking 1994-12-31 and showing -1995 for age.

```
$timestamp=strftime($data[5]);
        
            if(substr_count($timestamp,"-") > 0){
                $DateDelim = "-";
            } elseif (substr_count($timestamp,".") > 0){
                $DateDelim = "0";
            } else {
                $DateDelim = "/";
            }
            
            //$TMP_AGEDATE = date("m-d-Y", strtotime($data[5]));
            $TMP_AGEDATE=convertdate($timestamp,$_SESSION['current_DateFormat'],'usa',$DateDelim);
            $TMP_AgeDate=strftime("%m-%d-%Y", strtotime($TMP_AGEDATE));
            //echo $TMP_NAME." - ".$newDate." - age  ".getAge($newDate)."<br>";
            //
```

Comment: Where does MySQL factor in?

Comment: Tip: It's really odd to see things like `$TMP` in variable names. It's understood that some variables are temporary by nature, but that should be implicit in how they're scoped and used. What you really need here is a function that encapsulates what's going on here.

Comment: use carbon for this :) https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/ you will have an ->age attribut

Comment: 1. Remove irrelevant lines . 2. Use better variable names. 3. Fix your indentation. 4. Provide sample input *in* your code sample, we don't have a variable called $data. 5. Make sure people can *run* your test code. We don't have your `convertdate` function either.

Comment: Pretty bad idea to base this on `strftime` to begin with. Why work with a date formatted in a _localized_ format for this? And we don't know what `convertdate` does, but I doubt feeding it `0` as the date delimiter, when a `.` was found, makes much sense either.

Answer (score 0):

You can use carbon (https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

```
Carbon::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", "1985-08-06")->age // returns 37
```